# How to add new node when building Binary Tree

Tags: c#, binary-tree, nullreferenceexception

I'm working with an alternate version of the BinaryTree class called RedBlackTree. I'm trying to build the tree with this add method.

```
 public void Add(T val)
    {
        RedBlackNode<T> newNode = _rootNode;

        while(newNode != null)
        {
            if(val.CompareTo(newNode.Data) < 0)
            {
                newNode = newNode.LeftChild;
            }
            else if(val.CompareTo(newNode.Data) >= 0)
            {
                newNode = newNode.RightChild;
            }
        }
        newNode.Data = val;      //nullReferenceException thrown here  <---
        newNode.IsBlack = false;
        FixColors(newNode);
    }
```

_rootNode is a private field giving the root of the tree. It is initialized to null as given by specific instructions. This Add method is being called from within another class from a method that is reading in file info. On the first iteration, a nullReferenceException is thrown, I assume because the node I am trying to change is null. I don't know how else I am supposed to change the data value of these nodes. I will post the code to the rest of the program if necessary.

Comment: You need to check if _rootNode is null. If it is so, create a node using new keyword and assign it to _rootNode and exit this function

Comment: @Partha why? Code can only reach that point when `newNode` is null.

Comment: While I've considered this to be duplicate of [What is NRE and how to fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) in reality this is different question as OP explicitly finds null - so problem is not NRE, but rather the way how searching stops.

Comment: @OP I don't understand how the answer you've accepted could solve your problem. If you only make the change described in that answer, `newNode` is still guaranteed to be null at the end of the loop, and will result in the NullReferenceException you were describing earlier.

Comment: Actually it didn't solve my answer. I thought it would at first glance, but I'm still working on it. Your answer is another step in the right direction, although the instructions I am given also say that I am supposed to loop while the node != null. I'm still having issues implementing it that way without getting a nullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the while loop isn't going to exit while `newNode` isn't null. That implies `newNode` *is* going to be null once the loop exits. I think what you want is to create a new node if the `RightChild` or `LeftChild` nodes is null, and set `newNode` to that.

In addition, as Partha's answer points out, you need to initialize the `_rootNode` value if it isn't already set.

I don't really know how the parent property of the node is set, so I'm going to assume the parent node is injected as a constructor argument of the child node:

```
public void Add(T val)
{
    RedBlackNode<T> parent = _rootNode;
    RedBlackNode<T> target = null;

    while(target == null)
    {
        if(val.CompareTo(parent.Data) < 0)
        {
            if (parent.LeftChild == null) 
                target = parent.LeftChild = new RedBlackNode<T>(parent);
            else
                parent = parent.LeftChild;
        }
        else if(val.CompareTo(newNode.Data) >= 0)
        {
            if (parent.RightChild == null) 
                target = parent.RightChild = new RedBlackNode<T>(parent);
            else
                parent = parent.RightChild;
        }
    }
    target.Data = val;
    target.IsBlack = false;
    FixColors(newNode);
}
```

Comment: Need 1/2 upvote to each answer as for some reason only half of solution provided (but combined one would be correct).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't really understand what's going on in the other answer. Could you explain what I'm missing? I thought `_rootNode` was a property of whatever class contains this method (and as such it would be unlikely for `Add` to have to initialize it).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov In fact, the `_` prefixed member name convention is usually for readonly fields, so it isn't even clear you *can* change `_rootNode` in the method.

Comment: According to the question: "_rootNode is a private field giving the root of the tree. It is initialized to null as given by specific instructions" - so initializing it to something likely responsibility of `Add` for given assignment. Side note: I'd not make *any* assumptions based on variable names for homework questions - copy-paste creates varying names with no relation to scope/static/readonlyness :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Ah, right. I didn't even read that bit. EDIT: nvm, I understand how it could be null

Comment: homework is not expected to be logical - it generally designed to test particular piece of recently acquired knowledge about topic...

Comment: Alright, with a combination of your answers, I was able to follow the instructions given to me and still avoid the exception. This was my first question posted on this site and a great first impression. I will be sure to come here again if I have issues. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the node before you access the other fields. So if _rootNode is empty you create using new keyword.

```
public void Add(T val)
{
      if(_rootNode == null)
      {
           RedBlackNode<T> newNode = new RedBlackNode<T>();
           newNode.Data = val;
           newNode.IsBlack = false;
           _rootNode = newNode;
           return;
      }
      //Followed by your logic
}
```